# Problem with Entity Framework 4 and NUnit

Tags: entity-framework-4, nunit, entity

I've got a simple test project I'm trying to convert from the visual studio unit testing framework to nunit.  However, I'm encountering a strange error.

```
    private VidRepository _repository;

    //Setup the context before each test
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        var fakeRepository = new FakeRepository();
        _repository = fakeRepository.GetFakeRepository();
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanGetMakes()
    {
        var makes = _repository.GetMakes();
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, makes.Count());
    }
```

When I run the test CanGetMakes it dies in the TestFixtureSetup method with the error.

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'CompanyName.Data.VidEntities,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

I've added and removed the reference to the project a couple times with no luck, and it also works when I change it back to the Microsoft unit testing framework (using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;) which is very odd to me.

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Thank you,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I went through my projects and set the platform target to any cpu and it fixed the problem.